# Equivalence of Repeating Decimal

Tags: inequality, decimal-expansion, gre-exam

GRE exam question asks what is greater

$.\overline{717}$

or

$.\overline{71}$

I believe both are equal, but GRE says that $.\overline{717}$ is greater.

But why?

If they repeat for infinity, isn't the value the same, i.e.

$.71717171717171717171717171717171717171...$

Comment: The first one is 0.717717717717...

Comment: @Watson Oh wow, now I realize ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is $0.717,717,717\dots$ while the second is $0.717,171,717\dots$.  They differ in the fourth place.  Alternately, $0.\overline{717}=\frac {717}{999}$ while $0.\overline {71}=\frac {71}{99}$.  You can cross multiply to find which is larger.

Comment: You mean that dividing my 99, or 999 will give repeating decimals? That's interesting!

Comment: Yes, the classic way to convert a repeating decimal to a fraction takes you there.  If you have a repeat of $n$ digit length, you multiply by $10^n$ and subtract the original number.  So $x=0.\overline{717}, 1000x=717.\overline{717}, 999x=717, x=\frac {717}{999}$

Comment: That's an interesting way to look at numbers. I wish they teach this in elementary or middle school!

Comment: I learned it back then, quite a while ago.  It feeds the proof that every fraction can be expressed as a repeating decimal and is similar to the proof of the geometric sum formula $1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots = \frac 1{1-r}$ for $|r| \lt 1$